# is there a way to get all queued scripts/styles into a template without `get_header()`?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, scripts, css

in my main plugin page i check if a certain page is visited if so, i load a certain template. in the following way:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', array($this, 'includeTemplate'), 99 );
public function includeTemplate($template){ 
    global $wp_query;
    if(is_page() && $wp_query->query['pagename'] == 'my_page_name'){
       include(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'templates/my_page_name.php');
       die;
    }
    return $template;
}
```

my question is how can i load all the queue scripts and styles to this template without using `the_header()`

I've tried :

```
global $wp_scripts;
foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
    echo $handle . ' | ';
endforeach;
```

The above echoed `admin-bar`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_header()` does not even seem to be native WP function?

Technically getting header isn't what really causes styles and scripts to load, it's [`wp_head()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_head/) call that should be made there (and [`wp_footer()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_footer/) call in footer). So they are likely what you should be using.

If you do need something lower level you might want to look at:

- [`wp_print_styles()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_print_styles/)
- [`wp_print_head_scripts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_print_head_scripts/)
- [`wp_print_footer_scripts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_print_footer_scripts/)

Comment: well neither of the tree worked.. wp_head() does what it suppose to but for some reason it adds 2 hidden divs which i cant seem to find where the originate from

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you should be able to run the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) filter yourself.

```
do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

That should give you the best chance of loading scripts and styles without also loading other things that might be hooked into (rightly or wrongly) [`wp_head'][2], [`wp_footer`][3], or the`wp_print_styles` hook, which seems to be subject to abuse.

You may also want

```
do_action('wp_print_head_scripts');
```

and

```
do_action('wp_print_footer_scripts');
```